# feed from view doesnt work

Tags: views, feeds

I made a view which works fine in the page view, but clicking on the feed icon or going directly to the path for the feed gives a  http 500 internal server error on IE 11.

And on firefox it simply has a blank white page.

Why arent the feeds working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable the RDF module and now it works.